# Добавление данных в json, через форму

Tags: php, json

Почему после отправки корректных данных, файл data.json не дополняется?

Изначальный файл json

```
[
    {
        "email" : "test@test.ru",
        "age" : 18
    } 
]
```

Я проверил, если после `$data[] = ['email' => $email, 'age' => $age];`

вставить

```
echo '<pre>';         
var_dump($data);        
echo '</pre>';
```

то на экране показывает, то, что файл дополнился, а если его открыть, то он не изменён. Почему?

Может проблема в путях $fileName?

```
<?php

if($_POST){ 
    $error =[];

    $options = [
        'options' => [
            'min_range' => 18,
            'max_range' => 70
        ]
    ];
    $age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options);

    if($age === false){
        $error[] = 'Поле возраст должно быть больше 0 и меньше 70';
    }

    $email= isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

    if($email === false){
        $error[] = 'Поле Email не корректное';
    }

    //если нет ошибок, то значения в поля не подставлять
    if(!$error){
        $fileName = __DIR__  . '\data.json';
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName), true);

        $data[] = ['email' => $email, 'age' => $age];
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($data);
        echo '</pre>';

        //если не записали файл
        if(!file_get_contents($fileName, json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE))){
            $error[] = 'Ну удалось сохранить данные';
        }

        //это только пример, писать так не нужно
        if(!$error){
            //header("Location:./form3.php");
        }

    }
}

$fileName = __DIR__  . '\data.json';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName), true);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);
echo '</pre>';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Обработка форм</title>
    </head>
<body>

<?php 
if($_POST){?>
    <?php foreach($error as $error): ?>
        <p><?php echo $error ?></p>
<?php endforeach; }?> 

    <form action="form3.php" method="post">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';?>" placeholder="Email">


        <label for="age">Возраст</label>
        <input id="age" type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : '';?>" placeholder="Возраст">
        <input type="submit" value="Войти">
    </form>
<body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> //если не записали файл
> if(!file_get_contents($fileName, json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE))){
>     $error[] = 'Ну удалось сохранить данные';
> }
> ```

Здесь происходит чтение файла, а не запись.

Comment: Почему данные записываются в json, если в теле условия написано добавить элемент в массив?

Comment: if(!file_put_contents($fileName, json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE))){
   $error[] = 'Ну удалось сохранить данные';
 }